# Adding median values of several rasters (geotiff) to each fishnet polygon (200x200metres fishnet) using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, vector-grid, iteration

I have a 200x200metres fishnet of my study area, with a few attributes in it, like land use, percentage of each landuse class.

Now I need to add the median value of more than 10 rasters to the fishnet, and I have to repeat this process 30 times (30 fishnets with respective +10 rasters each).

In ArcMap I know the Zonal Statistics to Table is the appropriate tool but I have not been able to produce a ModelBuilder iteration that works in giving me all the raster values within columns with their names.

I don't know how to code in Python, but if there is any tutorial on how to do this ''for dummies'' I am willing to try.

Comment: Where precisely did you get stuck when trying to do this using ModelBuilder?  If you wish to ask the same question about QGIS, then please do so in a separate question so that you can describe what you have tried there too.

Comment: Without showing us your model can't really comment! Sounds like you simply need to join the output of zonal stat tool to your fishnet?